# Joomla 2.5 - Function getLanguage doesn't give current language

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I try to get the current selected language.

Here is the part of my code:

```
define('_JEXEC', 1);
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/defines.php')) {
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/defines.php';
}

if (!defined('_JDEFINES')) {
    define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__));
    require_once JPATH_BASE.'/includes/defines.php';
}

require_once JPATH_BASE.'/includes/framework.php';

$lang =& JFactory::getLanguage()->getTag();
```

and...

```
echo $lang;
```

always returns en-GB.

The website has the possibility of Ger and Eng. It also changes languages for different articles. I don't understand how I did not get the current selected language within php.

Comment: May I suggest you trying asking your question over at [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com) as it will get more attention there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was out of scope!!

Here is the solution:

```
// Set flag that this is a parent file.
define('_JEXEC', 1);
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/defines.php')) {
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/defines.php';
}

if (!defined('_JDEFINES')) {
    define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__));
    require_once JPATH_BASE.'/includes/defines.php';
}

require_once JPATH_BASE.'/includes/framework.php';


// Instantiate the application.
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');

// Initialise the application.
$app->initialise();


$lang =& JFactory::getLanguage()->getTag();
```